# Flash alternative for iphone app made with PhoneGap

Tags: ios, flash, cordova

What is the best way to implement Flash or some Flash alternative(converted swf into some othe format)? I am using PhoneGap for development. I can't use jquery mobile for that animation, because it is too hard to make.

Comment: what is wrong with a question? Why downvote? I am not sure what can I use for iPhone development with phoneGap instead of Flash, which is not supported on iPhone

Comment: Have you looked at the Swiffy extension for Flash?  http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/11/flash-developers-export-to-html5-with.html

Comment: Oh great... So, that's the solution I guess.. What do you think, is the quality the same? Thanks for response

Comment: Personally, I haven't used it.  We've dropped Flash development.  Recently, I replaced some animated Flash charts using Raphael JavaScript library (SVG-based).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your output is. 
Why not look at CSS- webkit animation ?

For simple stuff it works well. Look at apple implementation at iCloud.com :-)

An good starting point - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/webkit-keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: I need something more complex that regular CSS webkit animation, that's why I need Flash..